# Why cant i access my api controller in browser?

Tags: c#, .net-core, controller, webapi

i am using dotnet 5.0 webapi C# in visual studio. Im making a controller. When i enter the link: localhost:portnumber/api/hello It tells me it cant connect to it, and i cant get any values. Even though when i just access localhost:portnumber the webapplication seems to run fine.
Here is my controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Album.Api.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class HelloController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("{name}")]
        public string Get(string name)
        {
            var greeting = new GreetingService();
            string messagegreeting = greeting.Greet(name);
            return messagegreeting;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "Hello";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is not in the controller.  The controller is used to parse/deserialize the response.  The error is the URI in the request.

Comment: Do you get a 200, 404, or runtime error?

Comment: What can i do to solve it? Im just a beginner

Comment: I get 404 error.

Comment: What URL are you calling?

Comment: Im calling this https://localhost:44379/api/hello

Comment: I start my app in visual studio with: start without debugging

Answer (score -1):

Your api address will be:
/api/Hello/{name}

you must pass a name to your api:
/api/Hello/yourname

Comment: Then what is the url needed for the second controller method?

Comment: It will be like : /api/Hello

Comment: which is what the OP is currently using

Comment: I made a asp.net core application and put your code and it worked for me without any error, what is your error?